# Smoothen line on linerender

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a square using linerenderer but my problem now is that the line is not smooth. see below picture. I've tried enabling anti-aliasing and setting lr.numCapVertices to no avail.

[image]

```
 private void DrawLine()
{
    GameObject myLine = new GameObject();
    myLine.transform.position = start;
    myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));     
    lr.positionCount = 4;
    lr.startWidth = .1f;
    lr.endWidth = .1f;

    lr.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(1, 0, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(2, 0, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(2, new Vector3(2, -1, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(3, new Vector3(1, -1, 0));
    lr.loop = true;


    Gradient gradient = new Gradient();
    gradient.SetKeys(
        new GradientColorKey[]
        {
            new GradientColorKey(Color.red, 0.25f),
            new GradientColorKey(Color.green, 0.50f),
            new GradientColorKey(Color.blue, 0.75f),
            new GradientColorKey(Color.yellow, 1f),
        },
            new GradientAlphaKey[] { new GradientAlphaKey(1f, 0.0f)

        }
        );
    lr.colorGradient = gradient;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [line renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) documentation. Specifically the following properties:

- Corner vertices
- End cap vertices
- Alignment

The corner and cap vertices will determine the 'roundness' of corners and line endings.
Different alignment settings may give you a more orthogonal view of the line which should prevent the illusion of varying thickness as can be seen at the green corner in your image.